# WAMP server doesn't work properly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wampserver

I just upgraded my OS to Windows 10 and I have an atypical problem. 
I use WAMP server and PHP doesn't work, although no error is displayed anywhere.

I tried to update vcredist or to change ports, but the problem persists.

Comment: Turn off the service: world wide publish(W3SVC)

Comment: There are many possibilities. Like skype using port 80, for example, etc.

Comment: lol i dont have world wide publish in windows 10, and if i change port still all ok but the PHP doesnt work again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 does not come with all the older MSVC Runtimes installed.

You will also have to install any of these that are missing.

- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2008 (VC9)
  [32bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) / 
  [64bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)
- Microsoft Visual    C/C++ Redistributable 2010 (VC10)
  [32bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) / 
  [64bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2012 (VC11)
  [32bit & 64bit selectable on this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable    2013 (VC13)
  [32bit & 64bit selectable on this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2015 Update 1 (VC14)
  [32bit & 64bit selectable on this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984)
- VC15 Redistribuable (Visual C++ 2017)

  [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2017 x86](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe)

  [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2017 x64](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe)

*VC2017 (VC15) is backward compatible to VC2015 (VC14). That means, a VC14 module can be used inside a VC15 binary. Because this compatibility the version number of the Redistributable is 14.1x.xx and after you install the Redistributable VC2017, VC2015 is removed but you can still use VC14.*

### UPDATE April 2017

Most of the MSVC runtimes are now available [from this microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Which versions of the above you actually need to run WAMPServer, or rather Aapche, will depend upon the version of WAMPServer you are running, but installing all of them can do no harm as they are used by any software that has been compiled with the Microsoft compilers.

If you are using WAMPServer 64bit on Windows 10 64bit, you will need to install **BOTH the 32 and 64bit versions of these libraries**.

***After*** you have checked you have all the runtime libraries, you may also need to re-install the Apache and MYSQL services as the upgrade to Windows 10 unfortunately sometimes (pretty much always) misses the fact that you have 2 services running that should be replaced after the upgrade i.e. `wampapache` and `wampmysqld`

All you need to do is, using the wampmanager menus system do this :

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Services -> Install Service

left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Services -> Install Service
```

Then

```
left click wampmanager -> Start All Services
```

#### Additional info

Also remember that for PHP to be interpreted, the code must exist in a file with a `.php` extension. If you are using `notepad` as an editor, that will add a `.txt` to a filename, so if you save `tst.php` it will actually get saved as `tst.php.txt` and therefore will not run. Get a decent editor notepad++ will do a great job and is free.

Also files with the `.html` or `.htm` that contain php code will not execute the php code as these files are not passed to the PHP interpreter, because they dont have the `.php` extension.

#### Using Explorer

Dont double click on the script file name in Windows Explorer. This works to test pure HTML pages, or HTML + Javascript pages, **but it does not work if the page has PHP code in it** However doing this does not go via Apache, and it is Apache that see's the `<?php` tags and therefore know to pass this code to the PHP interpreter.

You must enter the script file name into the browser address bar, as if it were a real web site, **because of course it is**

For example `localhost/project1/test.php`

Comment: Still doesnt work. PHP error log: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Ok, in that case you will have to uninstall WAMPServer. Manually delete the `/wamp/` folder and all subfolders. Then reinstall WAMPServer. Remember to do this as `As Administrator`

Comment: Ok now no error but still no php. I tried every popular fixes with no solution. I dont know maybe I can check that using some commands in cmd ?

Comment: Do you see the WAMPServer homepage when you enter `localhost` in the browser?

Comment: In that case PHP is working as both of those are written in PHP

Comment: See additional info, does any of that explain your problems

Comment: But for example file:///C:/wamp64/www/index.php its just a text php isnt working there

Comment: See additional info called **Using Explorer**

Comment: Ok thank you 2 last questions. In localhost is the title "Your projects" why when I click on my project is redirects me to /myproject without localhost at the beginning? Another question is Why localhost/myproject/index.php redicts me to wampserver homepage(localhost)?

Comment: 1) Use Virtual Host http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757 2) Dont know, you had better add the code for that script to your question, use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36598500/edit) link

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem and solved it by installing 
Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2010 (VC10), both 32bit / 64bit as 2008 and 2012 were already installed. 
My configuration: windows 10 64 bit, wampserver 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem could be Skype running at the time you want to start your server, so you can

1. Stop SKYPE because SKYPE utilize port 80 and server wants to use same port.
2. Go to **httpd.conf file** and change the Port number from 80 to 8000/8080.
   -Left click Apache icon,
   -Go to Apache and open **httpd.conf** file,
   -Search and replace port 80 to 8000 / 8080
   -Save & close,
   -Restart the server again.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Wamp working with Windows 10 in 2020**

[image]

You can try this, I done the following things.

1. Install msvcp140.dll
2. Install Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable
3. Install wamp server
4. Close Skype (Chat App) if it is running

But wamp icon did not change its color to orange to green. (turning wamp icon orange to green means it start working). I installed wamp multiple time to make it color orange to green but it still show orange color. But actually, behind the scene it was working I checked it in browser by URL: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/