# The application was unable to start correctly 0xc0000142 error when I try to open xampp shell through control panel

Tags: php, xampp

Using the latest Xampp version with PHP 7

[image]

> [cmd.exe]
> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000142).
> Click OK to
> close the application

I get a message that the application cannot start when I click the `shell` button in XAMPP control panel.

I reinstalled XAMPP but it didn't work.
I Updated my environment tables to mysql/bin so I can globally use MYSQL.
I can open the xampp_shell.bat and I will probably do that for now.

Comment: Do you have some AV or ZoneAlarm firewall installed? I read these programs can interfere, try to add an exception or check the status of your system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598500/wamp-server-doesnt-work-properly-on-windows-10

Answer (score 6):

Well, I know this will sound like a dumb solution but it works for me. Click on the shell button many times until the command prompt window opens.

Comment: That DID work! I had to click it about 50 times but finally the shell opened and stayed open. Then I had to close the 50 error dialogs. Many thanks for the workaround!
I found this info on the situation, but didn't feel like rolling back windows updates. ugh. Much rather do your suggestion. :)
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/67sues/xampp_shell_crashing_with_error_code_0xc0000142/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Win10 (build 1703) could be the cause.

**Quick Fix:** set compatibility of xamp-control file to Windows 8 and run as administrator.