# How to fix XAMPP Shell from crashing

Tags: mysql, shell, xampp

So I recently installed XAMPP, following a YouTube guide along the way. I click the start actions for Apache and MySQL and everything was going smooth until when I click the Shell icon on the right side of the command panel and the cmd associated with it just opens for a brief second and immediately closes I kept clicking on it hoping for it to work and nope it still just opens for a brief second and closes.

I kept searching for possible solutions online and still, it doesn't solve the issue. I tried tweaking the config of the Apache and MySQL and it still didn't fix it. I also try reinstalling using different XAMPP versions and still the problem persists. I also tried running it as administrator and issue is still there.

Additionally I'm using Windows 10

If anyone knows a possible fix for this I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit: I screen recorded my XAMPP issue, here's the link to that video : https://youtu.be/h-lM250Pqwc

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using a Windows 10 OS

Comment: Did you change the password for the mysql root account?

Comment: Nope and tbh this is my first time using XAMPP and I'm just starting from the ground up, I haven't created anything yet. It's just that the Shell in XAMPP doesn't work, it just crashes for some reason I do not know.

Comment: Did you start MySQL well its mariaDB really, before attempting to run the shell

Comment: Yep, I start Apache and MySQL. The weird thing is the log doesn't display anything wrong when starting both of them, there aren't even any errors. It's just weird and idk why the Shell just won't run.

Comment: Its been a while, but I assume thats the mysql shell.

Comment: Is there a possible way to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the xampp control panel is run as administrator?

Comment: I tried running it as administrator and still the problem persists

Comment: I screen recorded my XAMPP issue, here's the link to the video
https://youtu.be/h-lM250Pqwc

Answer (score 11):

Same issue on Windows 11

Running `xampp-control` as administrator did the trick.  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436747/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000142-error-when-i-try-to-ope)

[Some alternative solutions](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/command-prompt-closes-immediately-after-opening-batch-file):

1. Run SFC scan
2. Edit the registry key to stop CMD from closing

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the xampp folder.
2. Search for xampp_shell.
3. Right click it and run it as administrator.

That's it!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What if the user does not have admin permissions?

Comment: Add detail description not only steps.So, User can know what the actual problem and why your steps act as a solution to fix the problem.