# My wampserver isn't working. How do I figure out why?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

Version 2.0
Apache Version:2.2.11
PHP Version:5.3.0
MySQL Version:5.1.36

The icon is white.
When I try running php, they don't work.
They are saved in C:\wamp\www
Does anyone know why it's not working or how I can figure out?
I am using Windows 10. (Can that be why?)

Comment: Have a look at the log files in C:\wamp\logs folder specially the apache_error.log file

Comment: @jeff What should I look for there?

Comment: Since the server isn't starting up there should be quite a few verbose messages as to why.

Comment: WAMP server icon colors are red -> orange -> green have never seen a white one. Red is when the server is unable to start up. Orange when there's something stopping a server service from starting. Green well that tells you every thing is running smoothly.

Comment: If you have Skype, turn it off fully and try restarting WAMP - it messes with port 80 from memory, which can cause issues for apache.

Comment: @Sand WAMPServer 2.0? That did go white sometimes, but its so old I forget the reasons why!!

Comment: You can also look at the Windows Event Log. Both Apache and MySQL write error messages there even before opening their own error logs in `wamp\logs`

Comment: Why are you using an OLD and UNSUPPORTED version of WAMPServer on Windows 10

Comment: First thing I would check is that you have installed all the OLD and NEW MSVC Runtime libraries. [See this answer for help getting all the required libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598500/wamp-server-doesnt-work-properly-on-windows-10/36598628#36598628)

Comment: You coudl also go to the [WAMPServer Backup Repo - Checks VC++ packages installed](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and download `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits)` if you are on a 32 bit windows OR `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)` if you are 63bit windows. You will find links to these at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I think I might just uninstall and then reinstall.
Thanks to all for your help!